# How do I use javascript regex to separate this text into groups such that each group has one set of instructions and the item(s) below it?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a block of text (without quotes):

```
INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 1
1. Item 1
2. Item 2
INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 2
3. Item 3
```

How do I use javascript regex to separate this text into groups such that each group has one set of instructions and the item(s) below it?

The output should be:

```
groups[0] = "INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 1
1. Item 1
2. Item 2

groups[1] = "INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 2
3. Item 3
```

I am a beginner, but I came up with this: `(?:^|\s)(INSTRUCTIONS:(?:.|[\s])*)+(?:$|\s)`, which obviously doesn't work. It produces two groups with the entire block of text in each group.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see responses in your input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
var str = "INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 1\n" + 
"1. Item 1\n" +
"2. Item 2\n" +
"INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 2\n" +
"3. Item 3"

var groups = str.match(/INSTRUCTIONS:((.|\n)+?)(?=INSTRUCTIONS|$)/g)
// ["INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 1
// 1. Item 1
// 2. Item 2
// ", "INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 2
// 3. Item 3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Knippers' answer is probably correct, but it requires some explanation.

In regex results arrays, the first element, `groups[0]`, is the substring that matched the whole regex, not a capture group. The actual capture groups start at `[1]`. In your regex, there is only one capture group.

I'm guessing that you don't know at compile time how many times `INSTRUCTIONS:` will appear in the string. This means that capture groups alone are inadequate, since you have to decide, at compile time, how many capture groups to include in the regex. The subexpression `(INSTRUCTIONS:(?:.|[\s])*)+` contains only one capture group; if it did match more than once, only the last match would be kept. So instead, you need a regex that matches just one section of the string, but ending with `/g` so that you can run it several times.

The other problem with your regex is that it doesn't match each section separately as intended; instead it matches the whole string at once, with the second `INSTRUCTIONS:` string matching part of the `(?:.|[\s])*` subexpression. Daniel gets round this using the `(?=INSTRUCTIONS|$)` expression, which can match either at the end of the string or just before the next `INSTRUCTIONS`. This idea of using `(?=...)` to allow the match to end just before `INSTRUCTIONS` doesn't solve the problem by itself; you also need to state that, of all the valid matches, the shortest one is the one we want. This is why he used the "lazy" match `(.|\n)+?`, instead of the "greedy" match `(.|\n)+`.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. It helped immensely and I would have marked it as correct, but Daniël Knippers gave the actual answer.

Comment: Likewise, nice explanation. I'll just upvote you then :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and search for new lines (`\r?\n`) that come before (`?=`) the word `INSTRUCTIONS` (case-sensitive).

**Note:** The optional `\r` is to check for carriage returns.

```
str.split(/\r?\n(?=INSTRUCTIONS)/)

// ["INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 1
// 1. Item 1
// 2. Item 2", "INSTRUCTIONS: Instructions 2
// 3. Item 3"]
```